# Maximum amount of data to load in browser memory

Tags: javascript, ajax, browser

I've got 440 text documents totaling 21.6MB that I'm using as the basis for a simple Javascript app that will analyze word frequency, common phrases, etc. The most important information about common words and phrases is in a concordance instance that loads with the page. It's a manageable 150kB or so. This concordance index maps phrases to the filenames of the documents where they originally appear.

I want to allow users to click on phrases and see them in the original context in the individual documents where they are found. My original plan was just to load the full document (avg 50kB) on demand via AJAX. This would involve a short delay.

I could also lazily load the pages after the app loads, then summon them on demand. I'm wondering if there is a rule of thumb for how much data one can load into memory like this. Is 21MB absurd? This would essentially be a very large JS object.

Comment: Modern browser will easily cope with 21Mb of data. I think your problem would come in performance.

Comment: Don't you have a database on the server? Then you could load partial contents on-demand.

Comment: This is all client side with AJAX, unfortunately -- for work I only have access to a CDN

Comment: What's the server side?

Comment: Server side is an in-house CDN in the style of Rackspace cloud files or the like. I can upload files, but have no ability to run server-side code. Lame, I know! Though a client-side solution to this sort of problem is extremely valuable. If doing such a project for a client, for example, it's far more durable to give them a bunch of files than to implement code on their server.

Answer (score 0):

21 MB is OK. Latest browsers are capable of handling huge documents without much hickups. E.g. our Jenkins (continuous integration) often shows me a 200 MB log, even colored/highligted.

Be careful with regex's over the whole page, traversing whole DOM, and stuff like that.

If you can choose the browser, I recommend Chrome which has much faster JS impl than Mozilla (unfortunately).

Comment: "Chrome which has much faster JS impl than Mozilla " - What? Your post was 2 lines saying 20MB is ok and then something random about regex, the dom, and then this...

Comment: But that I could chose the browser. Not clear when this is ever an option in web development.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, seems like you don't understand the question, right?

Comment: @ChrisWilson, you can, sometimes, for intranet apps. Well, then, the user will have to wait a while :) Mozilla's catching up recently but Chrome is unmatched. PS: I'm Firefox fan.